TypeError: Type string storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type address. --> contracts/test.sol:149:26:
I have been trying to compile my smart contract but I keep on getting this error. I know this is related to ^0.8.0 version of solidity but I don't really know how to fix it.
Here's my code for the same:
contract BattleBetting {
    using ABDKMath64x64 for int128;
    using ABDKMath64x64 for uint256;

    enum BattleType { Memecoin, CryptoInfluencer, Sports }

    struct Battle {
        address creator;
        BattleType battleType;
        uint256 minBet;
        uint256 totalBetAmount;
        uint256 startTime;
        uint256 endTime;
        bool isLive;
        bool isFinalized;
        uint256 opponent1Bets;
        uint256 opponent2Bets;
        uint256 opponent1StartValue;
        uint256 opponent2StartValue;
        mapping(address => uint8) opponentChoice;
        string opponent1;  // direct storage of names instead of addresses
        string opponent2;  
        address[] bettors;  // array to keep track of bettors
        mapping(address => uint256) bets;  // mapping to keep track of each user's bet
    }

    //.... some other logic

    function finalizeBattle(
        uint256 _battleId,
        uint256 _opponent1EndValue,
        uint256 _opponent2EndValue,
        bool _sportsWinner
    ) public {
        Battle storage battle = battles[_battleId];
        require(block.timestamp >= battle.endTime, "Battle duration has not ended yet.");
        require(!battle.isFinalized, "Battle is already finalized.");
        require(battle.isLive, "Battle did not go live.");

        uint256 winnerBetAmount;
        uint256 loserBetAmount;
        address winner;

        if (battle.battleType == BattleType.Memecoin) {
            // Determine winner by percentage change
            uint256 opponent1Change = (_opponent1EndValue * 100) / battle.opponent1StartValue;
            uint256 opponent2Change = (_opponent2EndValue * 100) / battle.opponent2StartValue;
            if (opponent1Change > opponent2Change) {
                winnerBetAmount = battle.opponent1Bets;
                loserBetAmount = battle.opponent2Bets;
                winner = battle.opponent1; // This line gives the error
            } else {
                winnerBetAmount = battle.opponent2Bets;
                loserBetAmount = battle.opponent1Bets;
                winner = battle.opponent2; // This line gives the error too
            }

I was expecting this to be compiled but I don't know how I can fix this code. Any suggestions would be helpful in this case. Thanking you all in advance.
